# Why launch.xib containing image is not appearing in ios 7 simulators and works perfectly in ios 8 simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am new in ios. I am facing one problem when i am using xCode 6 and setting one image in launch.xib and when i run in ios 8 simulators then launch image appears properly but when i run it in ios 7 simulators then that image is not coming what should i do to resolve it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

iOS 7 does not support launch images as interface builder files; it's a new feature in iOS 8 to support arbitrary display devices. You should add launch images if you are targeting iOS7 as well.

Comment: i have to use launch.xib as well as launch images both?? to target ios 7 and ios 8

Comment: That is correct, unless Apple were to release a new version of iOS 7 which has support for LaunchImages or unless there's a new Xcode which can automatically render the .xib into screenshots. You can use the simulators to grab screenshots though.

Comment: I have added both Images and xib but, It only works on iOS 8 and goes blank on iOS7 Devices

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and run you app on an iOS 8 simulator. This will pause the app at a perfectly rendered launch screen. Then you can comfortably capture the screen and save as a png for iOS 7 to use.

Comment: @MaciejSwic Thank you very much! You've just saved me endless hours of pain

Comment: Well, what about the status bar, simulator screenshots will have a status bar